# I am not clear this kind of HandlerThread usage

Tags: android

If I create

```
HandlerThread sWorkerThread = new HandlerThread( "launcher-loader" )
```

Then I create

```
Handler sWorker = new Handler( sWorkerThread.getLooper() );
```

`sWorker` how to work now? it working in main thread? Thank you.

Comment: `sWorkerThread` should call the `start` method before use it's looper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HandlerThread` is a `Thread` subclass, and you must call its `start()` method to activate the new thread. If the `HandlerThread` is not active, then its `getLooper()` method actually returns `null` (which, if passed to the `Handler` constructor, would cause a thrown Exception).

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
HandlerThread sWorkerThread = new HandlerThread( "launcher-loader" );
sWorkerThread.start();
Handler sWorker = new Handler( sWorkerThread.getLooper() );
```

With this code, `sWorker` would run in the new thread (not the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

Your `sWorker` can be used to send message to the message queue of `sWorkerThread`. All the work you send with `sWorker` will work on the `sWorkerThread`, not the main thread. Long tasks that can't be executed on main thread can be done on  HandlerThread.

See the introduction to Handler [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

The introduction to HandlerThread [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html).